# Pseudo-code for search in binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

I need the pseudocode for a C++ that will search through a tree to find the node with the value of “z”.

the function is given the root node to the tree to begin with.
The tree has the property where each node has at most two children nodes.
Each node has 3 properties: left child, right child, and value.

Comment: no, I was just asked this at an interview, I want to see how I did :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following pseudo-code will do what you want for a tree in ascending order.

```
def findval (node,lookfor):
    if node is null:
        return null
    if node.val is equal to lookfor:
        return node
    if node.val is less than lookfor
        return findval (node.right,lookfor)
    return findval (node.left,lookfor)
```

to be called with:

```
znode = findval (root, "z")
```

It will give you the node or null if no node exists.

If you want to avoid recursion, you can use the iterative solution:

```
def findval (node,lookfor):
    while node is not null:
        if node.val is equal to lookfor:
            break
        if node.val is less than lookfor:
            node = node.right
        else:
            node = node.left
    return node
```

---

Obviously, there's all sorts of enhancements you could make such as allowing a different order, or a callback comparison function, or allowing duplicate keys, but this is the canonical example of a binary tree search.

Comment: this solution assumes that the right node has values greater than the left node, but my question does not say that.

Comment: But that invariably is the case because such trees are created as search structures. If it is not the case, then you need a depth first or breadth first search.

Comment: The usual behaviour of a binary tree is ascending order. If that's not the case, simply switch around the conditions.

Comment: @fmunshi, the whole point of a tree is to order the nodes. It's a reasonable assumption to make that the children would be ordered.

Comment: what is the reason for putting the check for node being NULL at the beginning?

Comment: @fmunshi, that's so it can elegantly handle an empty tree (where root is null).